# Removing Duplicate Values in Nodes using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

I have below XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<SLOCDETAILS>
    <INPUT>
    </INPUT>
    <TABLES>
        <OUTPUT>
            <item>
                <PLANT>INDIA</PLANT>
                <SLOC>T150</SLOC>
                <MATNR>220250</MATNR>
                <CHARG>112233</CHARG>
            </item>
            <item>
                <PLANT>INDIA</PLANT>
                <SLOC>T152</SLOC>
                <MATNR>220250</MATNR>
                <CHARG>223344</CHARG>
            </item>
            <item>
                <PLANT>INDIA</PLANT>
                <SLOC>T152</SLOC>
                <MATNR>220250</MATNR>
                <CHARG>445566</CHARG>
            </item>
            <item>
                <PLANT>INDIA</PLANT>
                <SLOC>T152</SLOC>
                <MATNR>220250</MATNR>
                <CHARG>667788</CHARG>
            </item>
            <item>
                <PLANT>INDIA</PLANT>
                <SLOC>T152</SLOC>
                <MATNR>220250</MATNR>
                <CHARG>998877</CHARG>
            </item>
        </OUTPUT>
    </TABLES>
</SLOCDETAILS>
```

My XSLT is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Rowsets>
            <Rowset Name="List">
                <xsl:for-each select="SLOCDETAILS/TABLES/OUTPUT/item">
                    <Row>
                        <PLANT>
                            <xsl:value-of select="PLANT"/>
                        </PLANT>
                        <SLOC>
                            <xsl:value-of select="SLOC"/>
                        </SLOC>
                        <Material>
                            <xsl:value-of select="MATNR"/>
                        </Material>
                        <Batch>
                            <xsl:value-of select="CHARG"/>
                        </Batch>
                    </Row>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Rowset>
        </Rowsets>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My resultant XML IS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Rowsets>
    <Rowset Name="List">
        <Row>
            <PLANT>INDIA</PLANT>
            <SLOC>T150</SLOC>
            <Material>220250</Material>
            <Batch>112233</Batch>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <PLANT>INDIA</PLANT>
            <SLOC>T152</SLOC>
            <Material>220250</Material>
            <Batch>223344</Batch>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <PLANT>INDIA</PLANT>
            <SLOC>T152</SLOC>
            <Material>220250</Material>
            <Batch>445566</Batch>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <PLANT>INDIA</PLANT>
            <SLOC>T152</SLOC>
            <Material>220250</Material>
            <Batch>667788</Batch>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <PLANT>INDIA</PLANT>
            <SLOC>T152</SLOC>
            <Material>220250</Material>
            <Batch>998877</Batch>
        </Row>
    </Rowset>
</Rowsets>
```

Now I want only SLOC that are unique. So for this XML, the SLOC that should be populated should be `<SLOC>T150</SLOC>` & `<SLOC>T152</SLOC>`

`<SLOC>T152</SLOC>` is being repeated 4 times. i want to avoid that.

How can I achieve that using XSLT?

I'm sure there is a grouping method that can be used. Also does XSLT provide distinct-value kind of function that we can plug & play? Different approaches to resolve this issue will be very helpful.

Thanks !

Comment: If you are using Xalan, I believe that is XSLT 1.0 only. In which case "Muenchian Grouping" will be your friend here. See http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html for an excellent walkthrough. If you can't get it to work, just edit your question to show your attempt, and I am sure it can be tweaked. Thanks!

Comment: It would also help if you edited your question to show your expected output. Do you want to show just the first `Batch` for the `<SLOC>T152</SLOC>` element, or all batch values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <Rowsets>
    <Rowset Name="List">
      <xsl:for-each select="SLOCDETAILS/TABLES/OUTPUT/item[not(SLOC = preceding-sibling::item/SLOC)]">
        <Row>
          <PLANT>
            <xsl:value-of select="PLANT"/>
          </PLANT>
          <SLOC>
            <xsl:value-of select="SLOC"/>
          </SLOC>
          <Material>
            <xsl:value-of select="MATNR"/>
          </Material>
          <Batch>
            <xsl:value-of select="CHARG"/>
          </Batch>
        </Row>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </Rowset>
  </Rowsets>
 </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Note:  This method only selects one batch.  If that's okay then you are good.  If not, then what do you want to do with batch?  Material and Plant seem to be the same, so no problem there.

Comment: If you want the batch comma delimited, then consider using the Muenchian Method mentioned in a previous comment.  Unless you have a very small data set.

Comment: This solution works. At this moment, I dont care about Batch node. I just need distinct SLOC node. Thanks a ton for the solution.